# What does this(X, null) mean?

Tags: java

I have this part of code that I couldn't understand:

```
public FirstArray(ArrayList<double> grades)
```

What does `this(grades, null)` mean?

Comment: You need to provide more of the code.

Answer (score 9):

It simply calls another constructor taking a second argument, here with value `null`.

That's a common practice : instead of making two constructor implementations, you make the one taking all possible arguments (don't put too many of them, though) and you write a few other constructors calling the first one but not requiring the arguments themselves.